# How to make a 2D real-time Strategy camera controller in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been looking around for ages about how to do a Real-time Strategy camera for Unity in 2D. What I mean is that you should be controlling the camera with W, A, S, D and where ever I look its only 3D. I have been trying to write my own scripts but the camera never works and I am in dire need for help. I have tried so much but as a beginner on Unity, I really need help with this. If you can give me anything about how to get started in this matter I will be so happy.

Do you think I should use the Force method or that I should use another one that unity already has installed? I also tried using vectors but when I looked around everyone was using Vector 3 which only is for 3D unity.

Comment: Don't use physics on your camera. Just move the transform directly. Vector2 is the 2D equivalent of Vector3. Anywhere you would use Vector3 just use Vector2 instead (without the z parameter of course)

Comment: please provide us with your current implementation so that I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a single script to your camera.

```
public float speed =10.0f;
void Update()
{
Vector3 a = transform.position
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("W"))
    {
        a.position.y += speed *Time.deltaTime
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("S"))
    {
        a.position.y -= speed *Time.deltaTime
    }
transform.position =a;
}
```

You can adjust the speed to your needs. You can do this for other keys. Note GetKeyDown is called when a key is being held down. Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this even compile? `Vector3` doesn't have any overloads for `operator+` that take a `float` as a parameter

Comment: The error is because I am directly adding the speed to transform.position. I have edited the code try it now.

Comment: This still doesn't work because `tranform.position.y` is a copy of the value, not a reference to it

Answer (score 0):

Make a direction vector with `Vector3 direction = new Vector3();`

Manipulate the vector in the directions you want, based on the key:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) 
   direction += Vector3.left;
```

Adding the "built-in" Vector3.left will point the direction of the vector to the left, and you can add the other keys on top of that to get a final direction.

Then you can use `transform.Translate()` to move the gameObject (in this case you attached it to your camera) by passing the direction you calculated based on the keys being pressed as a parameter. Then multiply to get `direction * speed * Time.deltaTime`;